# Spatstat Help in R (Comparing two Point Sets)

Tags: r, spatial

I have a GPS pointset with two marks (Maple, Spruce) loaded into R with the Spatstat package.

I want to determine if there is a correlation with the spatial pattern between spruce and maple. What is the best approach for me using R and the Spatstat package?

I have already converted my data to a point pattern object, and stored my marks as a vector. I just am confused now as to what analysis to use.

Thanks

```
    mydat<-read.csv("languedocpointsCOMBINED.csv",header=T)
    rm(list=ls())
    str(mydat)
    attach(mydat)
    detach(regdat)
    library(spatstat)

    ##min/max
    min(mydat[,2])
    max(mydat[,2])

    ## convert data to point pattern object, stores marks as a factor/vector 
    mypattern <- ppp(mydat[,2], mydat[,1], c(3.216707, 3.217786),     c(43.56019, 43.56073), marks = mydat$Label)
```

Comment: Please provide an example of your data and code so far. Did you assign the marks to the point pattern as a factor, so it is a multitype point pattern? You can use e.g. the cross K-function to check if there is significant correlation between the two species. I would suggest you read chapter 14 of our recent book (http://spatstat.github.io/book/). Unfortunately, chapter 14 is not one of the free sample chapters.

Comment: Hi Ege- I did indeed make it as a factor. Here is a snippet:                mypattern <- ppp(mydat[,2], mydat[,1], c(3.216707, 3.217786), c(43.56019, 43.56073), marks = mydat$Label)

Comment: Thanks- I am going to check out your book right now and read up on cross k. After assigning the point pattern I just haven't been sure what type of analysis to do next. I will look more into cross K- but if you have more details I would love to know.